# <li> data-filter set value on document ready

Tags: jquery

I would like to set a data-filter in an `<li>` tag when the page starts. Now at start-up it shows me all the results. I would like to set only one.

```html
<div class="portfolio_filter portfolio_filter_2">
  <ul>
    <li data-filter=".architecture" id="btn_1" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>ARCHITECTURE</a></li>
    <li data-filter=".building" id="btn_2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>BUILDING</a></li>
    <li data-filter=".construction"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>CONSTRUCTION</a></li>
    <li data-filter=".design"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>DESIGN</a></li>
    <li data-filter=".painting"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>PAINTING</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first by doing some research on the subject and making an attempt to write the code. If you have issues with that code, then feel free to ask a question requesting debugging help. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So select one and hide the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use data- attributes. You can simply use css, add hidden class to all elements you want to be hidden when the page loads

```
.hidden{display:none}
```

and use jQuery to toggle the class with an action

```
.toggleClass('hidden');
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/